# Can I somehow support MVC 4 action parameter binding behaviour in ASP.NET Core 2.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

I am migrating ASP.NET MVC 4 application to ASP.NET Core 2.1 and almost everything is going well by far.

I have a controller with an action which looks like this:

```cs
public class SomeApiController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Post(Model model, int key1, string key2)
    {
        model.Key1 = key1;
        model.Key2 = key2;
        return Json(model);
    }
}
```

The `Model` is:

```cs
public class Model
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public int Key1 { get; set; }
    public string Key2 { get; set; }
}
```

I can send a json body that contains any of `Model`'s properties with combination of query parameters and MVC 4 will always correctly bind body to `model`, `key1` and `key2`.

The most needed type of request that works in MVC 4 looks like this:

```
POST /SomeApi/Post

{
    "model": {
        "text": "some-text",
        "number": 1
    },
    "key1": 42,
    "key2": "some-text-2"
}
```

or like this:

```
POST /SomeApi/Post?key1=42&key2=some-text-2

{
    "model": {
        "text": "some-text",
        "number": 1
    }
}
```

Please pay attention to nested `model` value in json.

This will be correctly bound to appropriate action parameters, but it **does not on ASP.NET Core 2.1**, at least by default.

What is obviously working in ASp.NET Core 2.1:

```
POST /SomeApi/Post?key1=42&key2=some-text-2

{
    "text": "some-text",
    "number": 1
}
```

---

Question: can I somehow support MVC 4 binding behaviour in ASP.NET Core 2.1 so I don't need to rewrite huge amount of frontend requests and/or backend modeling?

Answer (score 1):

Change the receive parameter type(add **[Frombody]** before parameter):

**Create a new model** to put the three parameters as fields in it:

```
public class NewModel
{
    public Model model { get; set; }
    public int key1 { get; set; }
    public string key2 { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
 public IActionResult Post([FromBody]NewModel newModel)
    {
        Model model = newModel.model; 
        model.Key1 = newModel.key1;
        model.Key2 = newModel.key2;
        return Json(model);
    }
```

Here is the test result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I did consider a solution like this, though it will need a large amount of refactoring work for the amount of endpoints I have.

Comment: @Lev Dimov , If you can't change the JSON format of the parameters you pass, this is probably the best way for you.

Comment: I gave up searching for a simplier solution (something like very smart mvc4-ish model binder) and decided to introduce some changes to frontend requests mechanism

Comment: @LevDimove, ok ,if this solve your problem , please accpet my answer .